# How to customize my-order page Pagination in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, woocommerce, orders

I'm currently using WooCommerce 2.6, but I noticed My-Orders page only have a simple pagination with 2 buttons only (Previous and Next). Is there any plugin or a way to edit the code so it shows a numeric pagination just like in Products page?

This is the numeric pagination in the products page

[image]

**UPDATE**

I added some buttons that redirect to the first page and to the last page, but I still need a way to add a numeric pagination.

[image: This is how My Orders pagination looks like now]

This is the actual code in `orders.php`

```
   <?php
/**
 * Orders
 *
 * Shows orders on the account page.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.6.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders', $has_orders ); ?>

<?php if ( $has_orders ) : ?>

    <table class="woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <th class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ( $customer_orders->orders as $customer_order ) :
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
                ?>
                <tr class="order">
                    <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <td class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                    $actions = array(
                                        'pay'    => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                            'name' => __( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' )
                                        ),
                                        'view'   => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                            'name' => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' )
                                        ),
                                        'cancel' => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
                                            'name' => __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' )
                                        )
                                    );

                                    if ( ! $order->needs_payment() ) {
                                        unset( $actions['pay'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( ! in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                        unset( $actions['cancel'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order ) ) {
                                        foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders_pagination' ); ?>

    <?php if ( 1 < $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) : ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-Pagination">
            <?php if ( 1 !== $current_page ) : ?>
                <a class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-Button--previous button" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders', $current_page - 1 ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Previous', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( 1 !== $current_page ) : ?>
                <a class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-Button--first-page button" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders', 1 ) ); ?>"><?php _e( '<<', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $current_page !== intval( $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) ) : ?>
                <a class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-Button--last-page button" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders', $max   = intval( $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) ) ); ?>"><?php _e( '>>', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $current_page !== intval( $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) ) : ?>
                <a class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-Button--next button" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders', $current_page + 1 ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Next', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info">
        <a class="woocommerce-Button button" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Go Shop', 'woocommerce' ) ?>
        </a>
        <?php _e( 'No order has been made yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_account_orders', $has_orders ); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps for those who uses already new version of WooCommerce (for example 3.6.2 or something like this) (or it might still work in 2.6) and you need to add bullets pagination in woo account orders history here is code which works

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'base'          => esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders') ) . '%_%',
    'format'        => '%#%',
    'total'         => $customer_orders->max_num_pages,
    'current'       => $current_page,
    'show_all'      => false,
    'end_size'      => 3,
    'mid_size'      => 3,
    'prev_next'     => true,
    'prev_text'     => '&larr;',
    'next_text'     => '&rarr;',
    'type'          => 'list',
    'add_args'      => false,
    'add_fragment'  => ''
);
echo paginate_links( $args );
?>
```

you can insert this code in the middle between the buttons and remove the standard next and prev buttons (or change `'prev_next' => true,` to `'prev_next'     => false,`) or just delete everything in between `<?php if ( 1 < $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) : ?>` and `<?php endif; ?>` if you don't need standard buttons

Comment: It's working. But what about "View All"? 
How can we set that?